# Changing the size of first latter in subtitle

Tags: css

I am using bootstrap css and have defined subtitle.

Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/m7xKK/1/)

```
    <div class="center-container">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRzqEv5GXTFGZ1jOzAMNldPJAB6qCU2LRaiiWsld9o7zN1gz_jKaQ" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
        <div class="subtitle">Intention from past</div>
        </div>
```

I want to make first letter font size `36` for `I` in subtitle.

CSS:

```
subtitle:first-letter {
    font-size: 34px !important;
}
```

but it does not make affect. what is the issue here?

Comment: Use `.subtitle`, it's a class.

Comment: you can omit !important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOPs ... You just forgot the period there `.` so it will search for an element called *subtitle* and not the `class`

```
.subtitle:first-letter {
    font-size: 34px !important;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7xKK/2/) *(Added `color` to indicate)*

Also, don't use `!important` as you won't need that..

Answer (score 0):

Put your 'I' of "Intention from past" in span tag.

<div class="subtitle"> <span style="font-size:32px";>I</span>ntentio from past </div>

I have used inline css. You can change it to whatever size you want;

You forgot to put . in css before subtitle:first-letter.

Comment: you forget to add fiddle